# Accessing a class protected field without modifying original class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am using some 3rd party library that exposes some type (returned by a method).

This type has some protected fields i am interested in, however i am not able to use them since their visibility is **protected**.

Here is a simplification of the problem:

```
public class A
    {
        protected object Something;

        public A Load()
        {
            return new A();
        }
    }

    public class ExtendedA : A
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // Get an instance.
            var a = Load();

            // Access protected fields (doesn't compile).
            a.Something = ....
        }
    }
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the compiler's error message?

Comment: I dont get it, the field is protected, but when you derive from that class, you still cant access the member ?

Comment: there's a big difference between calling `.Something` on an instance **known to be an `ExtendedA` vs `A`; that is why the protected isn't letting you have access. Eric Lippert has a series of articles on "why can't I access a protected member from a derived class?" - search for them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Description

You can access the Field using `this.Something` because your class is derived from `class A`.

If you want to create a instance of the `class A`, not your derived class, you can only access the field using reflection.

#### Sample using Reflection

```
public class ExtendedA : A
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Get an instance.
        var a = Load();

        //get the type of the class
        Type type = a.GetType();
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        // get the field info
        FieldInfo finfo = type.GetField("Something", bindingFlags);

        // set the value 
        finfo.SetValue(a, "Hello World!");

        // get the value
        object someThingField = finfo.GetValue(a);
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [Accessing Protected Properties and Fields with Reflection](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/40538-Accessing-Protected-Properties-Fields-with.aspx)

Comment: The problem is i need to access the field on a specific instance, not on " this"

Answer (score 2):

That's because you actually *can't* access it.
You can't call protected methods on any instance other than `this` (or `base`). 
Just because your code happens to be in a descendant of A does not mean that this rule suddenly changes.

Eric Lippert has an excellent explanation in his blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/why-can-t-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class.aspx

Comment: You can call protected methods on values other than `this` or `base` if their type is known to be identical to or derived from the type of the class in which the code appears. For example, if you have base class B with protected method M(), then derived class D can call (new D()).M().

Comment: @EricLippert: And once again I find myself rereading a blog entry I pointed to, to comprehend what's really going on.  
Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note also that this original article spawned half a dozen more that explore various aspects of this rule. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/protected/ for the lot of them.

Comment: Cheers! I've been reading your blog entries for some time now, and enjoy them immensely. I'm an avid reader, apparently and sadly though, not a thorough enough one :)

Answer (score 0):

By inheriting from A you create a new class (ExtendedA) which has a member **Something** that you can access from within ExtendedA

```
public class ExtendedA : A 
{ 
    public void DoSomething() 
    { 

        // works fine
        this.Something = .... 
    } 
}
```

Inheriting does not give you the ability to reach into an instance of A to change Something

```
public class ExtendedA : A 
{ 
    public void DoSomething() 
    { 
        var a = new A();

        // access level error
        a.Something = .... 
    } 
}
```

If you want to use the **Something** value you can do so within ExtendedA but only on the ExtendedA instance's own copy of **Something**.

hth, 
Alan.