# How to make an external object's field accessible in derivered class

Tags: c#, field, external, protected

I'd like to create a class for the following example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected int a;
}

class DeriveredClass : BaseClass
{
    protected int ownA;

    public void CopyFrom(BaseClass b)
    {
        ownA = b.a;
    }
}
```

But it seems to be impossible due to protection level. The issue is that "b" is an external object within CopyFrom() method.

The exact code I'd like to use it for is to create a Singleton object with a possibility of upgrading it to the object of derived type:

```
class MyLogicBase
{
    private static MyLogicBase s_Instance = new MyLogicBase();

    protected MyLogicBase() { }

    public static MyLogicBase Instance
    { get { return s_Instance; } }

    public static Upgrade(MyLogicBase newInstance)
    {
        newInstance.UpgradeInstance(s_Instance);
        s_Instance = newInstance;
    }

    protected virtual void UpgradeInstance(MyLogicBase previousInstance)
    { // To override }

    protected List<string> m_Database = new List<string>();
}

class MyExtendedLogic : MyLogicBase
{
    public override void UpgradeInstance(MyLogicBase newInstance)
    {
        m_Database = newInstance.m_Database;
    }

    // Extended logic here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just delegate the capability to the base class. You even have the virtual method `UpgradeInstance` declared in that class.

```
class MyLogicBase
{
    …

    public virtual void UpgradeInstance(MyLogicBase newInstance)
    { 
        m_Database = from.m_Database;
    }

    protected List<string> m_Database = new List<string>();
}

class MyExtendedLogic : MyLogicBase
{
    public override void UpgradeInstance(MyLogicBase newInstance)
    {
        base.UpgradeInstance(newInstance);
        …
    }

    …    
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for a fast respond. Accidentaly I wrote a code example which isnt showing the issue I'd like to solve. Im sorry for my mistake. Corrected it. The problem is I'd like the derivered class to setup itself using base class object, while base class object's fileds remain hiden from others.

Comment: @KamilKowalewski The solution is still the same. The `UpgradeInstance` virtual method is the right place where to copy the `m_Database` field. If, for any reason, you don't want a common behavior like this in the base class'es `UpgradeInstance`, declare another method for this purpose.

Comment: This makes it a little more complicated than I though it could be. Diffrent derivered classes could use diffrent base class fields in a diffrent ways. But this solves my current needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If its possible, you may create other 'protected method' in your base class something like:

```
class MyLogicBase {
    …
    public virtual void UpgradeInstance(MyLogicBase newInstance)
    {
         //to override
    }
    protected CopyDatabase(MyLogicBase newInstance) {
         m_Database = newInstance.m_Database;
    }

    protected List<string> m_Database = new List<string>(); }

class MyExtendedLogic : MyLogicBase
{
    public override void UpgradeInstance(MyLogicBase newInstance)
    {
        base.CopyDatabase(newInstance);
        …
    }
    …    
}
```

Alternatively, you could try to access the protected field using reflection, may be something along [Accessing a class protected field without modifying original class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698195/accessing-a-class-protected-field-without-modifying-original-class)